# How to get the top level key with the highest value of a specific lower level key in json file?

Tags: python

My json file looks like:

```
{
    "One": {
        "action": "One",
        "delay": 1558834290.2415142,
        "seconds": 60,
        "score": 10,
        "delta": 1558828290.2415142,
        "grace_sec": 6060
    },
    "Two": {
        "action": "Two",
        "delay": 1558834292.6928985,
        "seconds": 60,
        "score": 9,
        "delta": 1558828292.6928985,
        "grace_sec": 6060
    }
}
```

I want to get the top level key that has the highest value of `score`, so in this case I would want key `One`.

I've tried:

```
with open("streak.json", "r") as read_file:
                data = json.load(read_file)

highest = max(int(d['score'] for d in data.values()))
```

but I get TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'generator'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generate tuples of (inner_value, outer_key) to get the values that you want.

```
max((int(value['score']), key) for key, value in data.items())
```

this should evaluate to this tuple

```
(10, 'One')
```

which you can process as necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You could write it like this:

```
result = max(data, key=lambda k: data[k]["score"])
```